# I have an xml tags specified with namespace, what should be the correct xslt to transform it into required csv output

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I don't know how to make an XSLT for XML to convert it to CSV. Please code a XSLT for the given structure of XML with namespace.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:B3Msg xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/B3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<tns:InitSys>TESTSYSTEM</tns:InitSys>
<tns:InitSysRefId>654321</tns:InitSysRefId>
<tns:ValueDate>2016-05-04</tns:ValueDate>
<tns:ProdType>C:E:O:S:Cash</tns:ProdType>
<tns:TradeCaptureSystem>TESTSYSTEM2</tns:TradeCaptureSystem>
<tns:SysTradeid>AM:123456</tns:SysTradeid>
<tns:OpsfileId>
</tns:OpsfileId>
<tns:UniqueSysTradeid>AM:123456</tns:UniqueSysTradeid>
<tns:Cups>
<tns:LEG_NUM>0</tns:LEG_NUM>
<tns:MTM_USD>1475.210881</tns:MTM_USD>
<tns:MTM_LOCAL></tns:MTM_LOCAL>
</tns:Cups>
<tns:InitSys>TESTSYSTEM</tns:InitSys>
<tns:InitSysRefId>654321</tns:InitSysRefId>
<tns:ValueDate>2016-05-05</tns:ValueDate>
<tns:ProdType>C:E:O:S:Cash</tns:ProdType>
<tns:TradeCaptureSystem>TESTSYSTEM2</tns:TradeCaptureSystem>
<tns:SysTradeid>AM:123453</tns:SysTradeid>
<tns:OpsfileId>
</tns:OpsfileId>
<tns:UniqueSysTradeid>AM:1234578</tns:UniqueSysTradeid>
<tns:Cups>
<tns:LEG_NUM>0</tns:LEG_NUM>
<tns:MTM_USD>123456</tns:MTM_USD>
<tns:MTM_LOCAL></tns:MTM_LOCAL>
</tns:Cups>
</tns:B3Msg>
```

output: 
     InitSys,InitSysRefId,ValueDate,ProdType,UniqueSysTradeid,LEG_NUM,MTM_USD
     TESTSYSTEM,654321,2016-05-04,C:E:O:S:Cash,AM:123456,0,1475.210881
     TESTSYSTEM,654321,2016-05-05,C:E:O:S:Cash,AM:1234578,0,123456

Answer (score 0):

The following is not an elegant solution, but it does the job:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/B3"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    version="2.0"
    >
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>InitSys,InitSysRefId,ValueDate,ProdType,UniqueSysTradeid,LEG_NUM,MTM_USD</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="'&#x0A;'" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*/tns:InitSys" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tns:InitSys">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following::tns:InitSysRefId[1]" />
        <xsl:value-of select="','" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following::tns:ValueDate[1]" />
        <xsl:value-of select="','" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following::tns:ProdType[1]" />
        <xsl:value-of select="','" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following::tns:UniqueSysTradeid[1]" />
        <xsl:value-of select="','" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following::tns:Cups[1]/tns:LEG_NUM" />
        <xsl:value-of select="','" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following::tns:Cups[1]/tns:MTM_USD" />
        <xsl:value-of select="'&#x0A;'" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tns:*" priority="-10">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```